# Attaching a count variable to an object

Tags: yii, counting, cgridview

I need some help in showing a count of posts of each user in a CGridView.

For example:
I have a User and Post model.
I can access the posts of a user through $user->posts
Is there something I can add to have $user->num_posts

Answer (score 2):

You should simply use a stat relation, e.g. in your User model :

```
public function relations()
{
  return array(

    // ...
    'posts' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Post', 'user_id'),
    'num_posts' => array(self::STAT, 'Post', 'user_id'),
    // ...

  );
}
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/fr/database.arr#statistical-query

**EDIT** : 
You should also use eager loading to build your dataprovider, e.g. :

```
$criteria=new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with('num_posts');
```

About SQL queries, this should use only 3 queries :

- one query for gridview page count,
- one query to get users models,
- one query to get users num_posts.

Just take a look at Yii logs to be sure.

Comment: *we would end up with 2*N+1 SQL queries*. is that okay?. So i will end up with 500k+ SQl queries for 1 cgridview?. If i dont understand something can you explain? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getter in your Post model.
Something like this:

```
public static function getpostscount($id)
    {
        $total=0;
        $provider=Post::model()->findall('user_id=:user_id',array(':user_id'=>$id));
        foreach ($provider as $data)
        {
                if ($data->userid==$id)//userid name of column with user id in post model
                {$total++;
                }

        }
        return $total;
    }
```

Then in your view just pass user->id to getter and it will return you count of posts for this user. Something like this:

```
echo "User have".Post::model()->getpostscount($user->id);//$user->id is id of user for wich we will look count of posts
```

Regards.

Comment: Can't you just execute an SQL statement to avoid getting all data from the posts (findall) and just let the SQL server return a count? That would be much faster, imo. What you think?

Comment: I didnt test speed with sql count and this getter.In my case because i have cgridview with thousands of users and count of lists from list model for them. It works fine but i will try with sql. Thank you.

Comment: And sorry i lied cause i have this sql statement `$provider=Lists::model()->findall('user_id=:user_id', 
                  array(':user_id'=> $criteria));`.

Comment: if it would be something like count(*) then yes its way faster. In this case i dont see difference. time ~ same. Count here is same select where with autoincrement variable.